# how to dynamically update UIlabel text in two UIViews Same Time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, math

i have two uiview's named question and answer.
the question view is loaded from a cell's click.
on the question view i have two iboutlet buttons named "view answer" and "next"
when i click on button named "answer" the answerview loaded.
both uiviews have one label.now i want to display a question when the first time question view loaded and the related answer should be on the answer view's label. now when click on next button.the label should be updated and the relevant answer also. when all the questions are finished i want a view with score that how many answer was correct and how many was wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Where are you stuck?

Comment: i am stuck at question view. i have two arrays.one with Question's
and one with answer's now how do set the label's text on both views at the same time

Answer (score -1):

Great idea Rahul!

You must design you app to have an "engine" and an "interface".
The engine must know the questions, answers, answered questions and total points.
After you connect the user interface.

You UIButton view answer has a procedure for the click event. When the user clicks the button, you have to:

1) Know what is the current question number
2) Get from the engine the answer
3) Check if the answer view is created
4) Create the answer view if nil
5) Pass the answer to the answer view - the answer view updates the answer label
6) Pop the answer view visible

No need to update the answer when the user clicks Next.

Add multimedia and it will rock! Good luck!

Richard